# Getting Text To Fit A Shape

Tags: vba, text, powerpoint

I am coding using PowerPoint VBA and am trying to place text inside a rectangle shape, but ensure that the text fits (so there is no overflowing). I do not want the shape itself to resize, but the text to resize.

I have seen that I can use

```
oShp.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
```

However, the problem with this is that the text will only resize after the user has clicked on the textbox when PowerPoint is in normal mode. I want this functionality when the PowerPoint is running!

I would be grateful to know is there a way to get the text automatically resized or do I need to find an alternative method?

Thank you for any comments!

Comment: PowerPoint just doesn't respond much to content that changes during a slideshow. I think you may have to find an alternate method.

Comment: I tried a bunch of things and couldn't get the AutoSize to trigger (which is funny as WordWrap does). As John says above ... I can't see it working. Also ref Jamie's answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796993/trigger-powerpoint-text-autofit-behavior-without-displaying-application-window

Comment: Thank you very much much John Korchok and TechnoDabbler. This is the sort of frustrating type of issue that comes with coding in PowerPoint VBA! Yes - I have had to toy with using do loops and trying to resize the text automatically. I shall have a look at the StackOverFlow link above and see if it can provide some better code to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I would answer my question and close the thread.
After doing much research I found that there was no apparent method to get the text to auto-resize itself when the PowerPoint Show runs. I tried a number of approaches e.g. inserting text, trimming the text and turning word wrap off and on - however, none of these worked. I note (Bhavesh) I was fully aware of how to select the auto-size text settings via PowerPoint's GUI.

In the end my solution was to make a do loop and change the size of the text.

Below I pasted my key lines in the hope that it might help someone else who is trying to do the same. I made a variable overflow which attempts to assess if the height of the shape's textbox is bigger than the size of the rectangle.

```
Dim overflow As Integer
Dim counter As Integer    

counter = 0

With ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(stringToTest)
                    
overflow = CInt((.TextFrame.TextRange.BoundHeight) - (.Height - .TextFrame.MarginTop - .TextFrame.MarginBottom))
                    
Do While overflow > 16 And counter < 50
'*** I note that the shape is overflowing when its value is >0 but I found 16 to be the most "aesthetically pleasing" number!
'*** Also using a counter prevents the code from potentially getting stuck in an infinite loop

If .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size > 20 Then                                
.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size - 1
Else
.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size - 0.5
End If
'**** By reducing the font size by 0.5 this provided a better fit for the text _
'**** (even better than using on PowerPoint's auto-size function!)

counter = counter + 1
overflow = CInt((.TextFrame.TextRange.BoundHeight) - (.Height - .TextFrame.MarginTop - .TextFrame.MarginBottom))
Loop

End With
```

Comment: Smart! I assumed mine worked because I import text from Excel during SlideShow Mode and the text within the textbox seemed to automatically resize.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In shape format, under text options, choose the option to shrink text on overflow.

Then, using `.Shapes("Title 1").TextFrame.TextRange` we input text via VBA.

The text automatically changes its font size.

Comment: Bhavesh Shana - thanks for the post - but this is what I had done in the first place. The whole point of my thread is that when the text is inserted via VBA then the text does not resize. It only resizes when the user is in normal mode and clicks on any textbox (and then all textboxes are resized). Surely if I had not activated this feature in the first place then I would not have been able to write in my opening thread that the text only resizes after clicking on the textbox?)